# How do I minimize my installer in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I created my own custom minimize button in Inno Setup.

I would like to know how to minimize my installer when I click on it.

The minimize should be just like the default minimize button on the border of the installer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To simulate a click on the minimize button in a window title, send [`WM_SYSCOMMAND` message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) to the installer wizard form using the [`PostMessage` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_postmessage):

```pascal
const
  WM_SYSCOMMAND = 274;
  SC_MINIMIZE = $F020;

procedure MinimizeButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(WizardForm.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, 0);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

```
procedure MinimizeBtnClick(Sender: Tobject);
begin
 SendMessage(WizardForm.Handle,$112,61472,0);
end;
```

Comment: That's exactly the same code as my answer shows. You have just used hexadecimal notation, where I've used decimal notation, and vice versa.

Comment: Im sorry mr. According to me, in programming we can use many different codes but all it same means. So, please appreciate people to answer a question. Thanks sorry if i distrub you